# SQL join multiple columns into different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables name Combine and Product , combine has multiple products inside and combine has strictly 3 products so that i have two tables strutred as below:

```
Combine | id | name   | image                   | item1 | item2 | item3
          1  | exmpl  | www.exmpl.com/exmp.jpg  | 3     | 2     | 16 

Product | id | name          | image                           | stock   
          2  | productexmpl  | www.product.com/product2.jpg    |  3    
          3  | productexmpl2 | www.product.com/product3.jpg    |  7 
          16 | productexmpl3 | www.product.com/product16.jpg   |  3
```

What i want to get is search by combine id like `SELECT * FROM Combine Where id = ''` and get combine products in different rows , what i've tried is join tables with `SELECT * FROM Combine as c JOIN Product as p on c.item1 = p.id AND c.item2 = p.id AND c.item3 = p.id` but it joins information horizontally what i want is to get information vertically which means in different rows as below

```
  id | name          | image                           | stock   
  2  | productexmpl  | www.product.com/product2.jpg    |  3    
  3  | productexmpl2 | www.product.com/product3.jpg    |  7 
  16 | productexmpl3 | www.product.com/product16.jpg   |  3
```

i dont know if the structre is wrong by design but any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your example, but you could solve this by joining to the table 3 times, once on each statement. "JOIN product AS p1 ON p.id = c.item1" "JOIN product AS p2 ON p2.id = c.item2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image, p.stock
FROM Combine as c
inner join
Product as p
on (c.item1=p.id or c.item2=p.id or c.item3=p.id)
Where id = ###
```

Comment: Thank you , so basically or is doing this join separately for us